# Updating each element in MongoDB database in for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an array of userIDs (MongoDB `Objectid`s)which I want to iterate through and for each one, find its user entry in my MongoDB database of users, and update it, say modify the user's age. Then only when every user has been updated, do I want to say `res.send(200);` in my `Node.js` Express app.

I started out with the following code which is just plain wrong because of the asynchronous calls to `findById`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < userIDs.length; i++) {
    var userID = userIDs[i];

    User.findById(userID, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Update user object here

        user.save(function (err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(200);
        });
    });
}
```

Any ideas how I can do this? Is there perhaps a synchronous version of `findById`? Or perhaps a way to `map` through the array and apply a function to each element?

Thanks!

Comment: "just plain wrong because of the asynchronous", are you real? it is intentionally asynchronous not to block

Comment: @IlanFrumer what I meant is me doing `res.send(200)` in the asynchronous block is plain wrong when I have multiple objects to update. Of course I know it is intentionally asynchronous not to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the `forEach` method of npm's `async` module. It would look something like this:

```
async.forEach(userIDs, function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        user.save(function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            callback();
        }
    }, function(err){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.send(200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't `throw` in the iterator function.  You should instead pass the error to the callback `callback(err)` (if you want to stop the iteration) or ignore it (if you want to ignore it).  You really shouldn't `throw` in any asynchronous code, actually.

Comment: Wow thanks for introducing the `async` library! It's got some amazing functions in there! This worked!

Comment: Duly noted, Aaron Dufour. I've actually been trying to decide the best place for such errors to finally be consumed.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use promises.

An example with Q#all:

```
var q = require('Q');

var promises = userIDs.map(function(userID){

  var deferred = q.defer();

  User.findById(userID, function (err, user) {
     if (err) return deferred.reject(err);

    // Update user object here

    user.save(function (err, user) {
      if (err) return deferred.reject(err);      
      deferred.resolve(user);
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;

});


q.all(promises)
  .then(function(users){
    res.json(users);
  })
  .fail(function(err){
    res.send(500,err);
  });
```